# jQuery UI Slider Detect Slider handle Drag & Drop Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

can you detect the drag & drop event of slider handle ? I found only this events
- slide
- change
- start 
- stop

but i need the drag event. how can you detect it ?

```
$(".slider").slider({
    value   : 3
    min     : 1,
    max     : 5,
    step    : 1,
    slide   : function(e, ui) { },
    change  : function(e, ui) { },
    start   : function(e, ui) { },
    stop    : function(e, ui) { }
})
```

Comment: Why is it that you want to detect the drag event since it would overlap the slide event? `drag` = `slide` in slider. You can drag it on the axis only

Comment: i want to draw my custom slider range

Answer (score 5):

### http://jsfiddle.net/e4tr7/34/

the drag event is start and the drop event is stop

```
$(".slider").slider({
   slide : function(e, ui) { 
   //user is dragging
   },
   stop    : function(e, ui) {
   //user has dropped            
   }        
});
```

Comment: Actually the `slide` is `drag` , `start`=`dragStart` and `stop`=`dragStop`

Comment: sorry, forgot about that, very easy misconception.